# Disable new cPanel account creation in WHM

Tags: cpanel, whm

We have several devs and a few different WHM boxes. Is there a way to disable account creation on some of the servers? Or show an extra warning?

This is purely meant to be an extra check to make sure someone doesn't read our internal docs wrong and add an account to a box that it shouldn't be added to.

Comment: Devs should not generally have admin rights/passwords to the machine. You should be creating a user account on each machine and specifying access rights. I am sure cPanel does this. I do not use cPanel so I cannot tell you how. This is the route you should be taking and not trying to cripple or modify an existing app that is already designed correctly, but not used correctly. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

WHM/cpanel is nothing more than a GUI on top of your OS (usually linux).  The whole purpose is to make using a linux server easier for the average user.

You can't disable account creation on a linux box though you can prevent non admins from creating accounts.  Similarly, you can't limit account creation in WHM.

The question I would ask back is why developers even need WHM access.  Most functions are available through cPanel and accounts can't be created there.

Comment: Right or *wrong* our devs generally create the account and make the initial connections via DNS/other services. We typically never have issues, but I was attempting to hinder the "business as usual" from happening on certain boxes as we shift away from WHM/cPanel.